# How to achieve 'Advance Mastery'?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> *"Have Hacking, Mind Control and the Battery all active at once."*

I've activated them all, simultaneously, while in a battle, and still didn't got this achievement, any advice?

Comment: BTW - I've activated the Battery, than used it to power the Mind control & Hacking.

Comment: Tried again: Activated all, deployed hacking, paused, activated mind-c & battery, still didn't got it.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't activate the hacking drone after it attached itself to the other ship. Can't see anything else wrong with your approach.

Comment: @npst: Indeed, just figured it out, post as an answer plz...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve it you need to activate all at once, just as instructed.

**REMARK** - after the Hacking Drone attached itself to the other ship, activate it via the Hacking-System panel.